Flutter injectable package to inject AppLocalizations
I have a cubit that looks like this:
@injectable
class SomeCubit extends Cubit<SomeState> {
  SomeCubit({
    required this.logger,
    required this.someRepository,
    required this.flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin,
    required this.l10n, // AppLocalizations
    required this.anotherRepository,
  }) : super(SomeInitial());
}

Running the injectable generator throws an error about InvalidType because AppLocalizations isn't set up, but nothing I try allows AppLocalization to be injected.
I've tried doing it under the AppModule using @factoryParam, but it fails to generate code and fails out early. I've also tried applying the @factoryParam attribute in the SomeCubit constructor, but the same issue comes up.
Is anyone aware of how to do this and pass the current context in when attempting to get the SomeCubit dependency? I feel like there is a way to get this to work, but I'm missing something.
To summarize, I would like to use injectable with AppLocalizations.

So the issue is with injectable when it tries to generate the config.dart file.
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'; is not an import that flutter will automatically add and it has to be pasted in manually all over the place. Since injectable couldn't automatically add this import it resulted in the generated file using InvalidType as a stand in which obviously broke the generated file.
I came up with two options that worked.

I removed the AppLocalizations parameter and instead passed in the BuildContext using @factoryParam. This worked, but I was worried about the context becoming outdated. Example:

@injectable
class SomeCubit extends Cubit<SomeState> {
  SomeCubit({
    required this.logger,
    required this.someRepository,
    required this.flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin,
    @factoryParam required this.buildContext, // BuildContext
    required this.anotherRepository,
  }) : super(SomeInitial());
}


I only used AppLocalizations in one method that was called when a button is pressed. I changed the method to take BuildContext context and then call AppLocalizations.of(context) from within that method. I went with this since the context would always be up to date and correct.


Do you define your package's localizations delegates in the app's MaterialApp?
like so:
import 'package:your_package/l10n/app_localizations.dart' as your_package;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:your_app/core/app_router.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router( // example from app using GoRouter..
      title: "Your app",
      localizationsDelegates: _localizationsDelegates, // set loca delegates here
      supportedLocales: _supportedLocales, // set supported locales here
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      routerConfig: appRouter,
    );
  }

  Iterable<LocalizationsDelegate<dynamic>>? get _localizationsDelegates => [
        AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates, // your app's loca delegates
        ...your_package.AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates, // your package's loca delegates
      ];

  Iterable<Locale> get _supportedLocales => [
        AppLocalizations.supportedLocales, // your_package's locales need to include the app ones
      ];
}


localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates, supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
I set them like this.

you've set just the app's ones delegates.
Do I understand correctly, that you have an package in your app that has it's own localization? An that localization is not working in you app?
